# What should I put in contentDescription attribute for decorative images such as field separator?

Tags: android, accessibility

I gave an empty string.  Lint still complains.

```
<ImageView style="@style/DetailFieldSeparator"/>

<style name="DetailFieldSeparator">
  <item name="android:src">@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_textfield</item>
  <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:scaleType">fitXY</item>
  <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
  <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I usually just make separators views with backgrounds instead of imageviews.  Then you will not get the warning.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can set the content description of a purely decorative image to "@null" to avoid Lint warnings and let the screen reader know to skip that image.

```
<ImageView
    style="@style/DetailFieldSeparator"
    android:contentDescription="@null" />
```

Comment: nice! That's a great work-around to avoid the nagging lint error

Comment: Just keep in mind people who have sight problems heavily rely on these descriptions to navigate the app.

Answer (score -2):

I fix that warning by creating a text inside res/values/string.xml. Then I simply need to reference that text from all my imageviews

Comment: I know I can fix the warning by setting contentDescription to something to the effect of "Decorative Image".  But the screen reader will read it out verbatim.  I want something screen reader knows to skip.  That's why I tried empty string which is what you do for web pages.  But the warning is still there.

Comment: This is not a good practise. You'll have screen readers reading all the time the same text. Very bad thing.